# List all the Mercurial projects in Mercurial repo with python api

Tags: python, mercurial

I want to list all the projects using Mercurial with Python.
I downloaded the package "import hglib" but I did not find in the documentation, the functions, etc... which could help me. Somebody is would know how can it be done?

PS: i found some informations in this links:
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi
- http://pythonhosted.org/hgapi/index.html#hgapi.hgapi.Repo.command

but it wasn't what i was looking for...

Answer (score -1):

So, what I Understood from your question is probably you want to list the nested repositories inside a mercurial repo. In much more easier terms you must be working with a mercurial forest and you want to list the sub repos deep under and it seems that there is a python package named **hgnested** written to deal with mercurial forests.

I took a patch of code and played with it to meet what we want and this is what I came up with.

```
from mercurial import hg, ui
import hgnested

def getNestedRepos(ui, source, **opts):
    origsource = ui.expandpath(source)
    remotesource, remotebranch =hg.parseurl(origsource,opts.get('branch'))
    if hasattr(hg, 'peer'):
        remoterepo = hg.peer(ui, opts, remotesource)
        localrepo = remoterepo.local()
        if localrepo:
            remoterepo = localrepo
    else:
        remoterepo = hg.repository(hg.remoteui(ui, opts), remotesource)
    return remoterepo.nested

print getNestedRepos(ui.ui(), <path to mercurial forest>)
```

But there is another scrapy way where you need to visit all the sub directories recursively and look for the presence of **.hg** file.

**Note:** If you want to list repos from a remote repository make sure hgnested package is installed in that remote server and the repo path you are passing is a mercurial forest head.

Comment: NB: You're not supposed to use the internal API, because it can change whenever the devs feel like it.  No guarantees it keeps working.  Chances are "good" the code above will not work anymore on current Mercurial.